# Always visible menu component with list

Tags: html, css

Hello I want to have a three part detatched menu component that has header and footer always visible on the page. Let us consider we have list of several options to be choosen and if there are too many of them they are being scrollable so that footer is always visible as in many menus on smartphones:

```
    [    HEADER    ] --> always visible on top
      [   Title  ]
    [--------------]

    [---OPTIONS----] --> scrollable if screen is too small
      [Select 1  ]
      [Select 2  ]
      [Select 3  ]
      [Select 4  ]
      [Select n  ]
    [--------------]

    [    FOOTER    ] --> always visible on bottom
      [  Apply   ]
      [  Cancel  ]
    [--------------]
```

Could you please show me proper styling for these probably vertically stacked divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with CSS adding fixed position, you can see here for example:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp